# make PHP variable or array not exist out of the function where it was set

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have the following php functions.

```
function a() {
    $var = "variable";
    return $var;
}
function b() {
    $arr = array('a','r','r','a','y');
    return $arr;
}
```

And some more PHP out of those functions.

```
$var = a();
$arr = b();
print_r($var);
print_r($arr);
```

`$var` and `$arr` are defined in functions, but then are redefined outside of the functions. How do I make it so that the variables and arrays out of the functions are separate from the ones that are in the functions, so that the variables and arrays in the function don't exist out of the function?

Comment: As soon as a function returns, everything inside is "destroyed" anyway. What exactly do you want to do? Do you experience any problem?

Comment: They *are* separate; you don't need to do anything to make them separate. Having the same name does not mean they are the same variables.

Comment: But please learn some programming basics before going into web development. Even a $0.00 introduction tutorial to (even language-neutral) programming has something on variable scope. This will let you have a more satisfying experience with web development, too. If you have that kind of doubts, I hate to say but.... you won't go very far and it can be frustrating. PHP has a number of weirdnesses, it's *duck typed*, and it's not easy at it seems. Not easy to debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions have their own scope. Your function variables do not exist outside of the function unless they are defined using the `global` keyword. You may be confusing yourself by using the same variable names both inside and outside of the functions. Try changing the function vars to `$fx_arr` and `$fx_var`, respectively. You will see that they do not exist outside of the functions.

Comment: Okay, Thanks! This helped. My real problem was somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read more carefully [evariable scope in php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

`$var` declared in `a()` is only visible within `a()'s` scope. The same goes for `$arr` in `b()`.

This piece of code `$var = a();` should be read this way:

create global (for the scope of the document) variable `$var` and assign the value returned by `a()` to it.
stepping to `a()` we have:
create local (only visible in function scope) variable `$var` and assign 'variable' as value, then return the value of `$var`.

At the end you ended up with two variables with the same name but with different scope, they do not overlap/overwrite each other because of that.

The opposite is valid too, global variables are not visible in function scopes. You need to use global operator to make them (import them) visible in functions scope.

Hope that helps you. :)